# Kinetic-js: How to cache a complete layer as an image

Tags: performance, caching, kineticjs

I have a problem an hope to find any solution for it.

I am using Kinetic.js to create a HMI solution with special look-and-feel. Therefor I have created a function that creates 3 layers for a stage: a background layer with a grid, a layer with static shapes for the base layout of the HMI-screen and the third layer for all interactive elements (like buttons, valuedisplays and so on...). Now I want to cache the grid and the static layer to improve performance, because this layers will never change until the whole HMI-screen will change...

As a test I started to code the caching for the grid layer using the following code:

```
// Create a grid layer if showGrid is set to TRUE...
console.log('Start to create background grid if required');
if (this.actualPageConfig.showGrid) {
    var grid = new Kinetic.Layer();
    for (var x=1; x <= this.cols; x++) {
        var eLoc = LCARSElements.posToRealPos(x, 1, this.cols, this.rows);
        if (x <= this.actualPageConfig.columns) {
            grid.add(new Kinetic.Line({
                points: [eLoc.x, eLoc.y, eLoc.x, eLoc.height],
                stroke: "red",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                lineCap: "round",
                lineJoin: "round" 
            }));
        }
    }
    for (var y=1; y <= this.rows; y++) {
        var eLoc = LCARSElements.posToRealPos(1, y, this.cols, this.rows);
        if (y <= this.actualPageConfig.rows) {
            grid.add(new Kinetic.Line({
                points: [eLoc.x, eLoc.y, eLoc.width, eLoc.y],
                stroke: "red",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                lineCap: "round",
                lineJoin: "round"
            }));
        }
    }

    // Add grid layer to stage
    //this.stage.add(grid);  <-- to be replaced by cache image

    // Convert grid into an image and add this to the stage
    console.log('convert grid to image to increase performance');
    grid.toImage({
        width:      displayManager.stage.getWidth(),
        height:     displayManager.stage.getHeight(),
        callback:   function(img) {
            var cacheGrid = new Kinetic.Image({ 
                image:  img,
                x:      0,
                y:      0,
                width:  displayManager.stage.getWidth(),
                height: displayManager.stage.getHeight()
            });
            console.log('insert grid-image to stage');
            displayManager.stage.add(cacheGrid);
            console.log('redraw stage...');
            displayManager.stage.draw();
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is, that's not working. The grid is not visible any more and the console log shows the following error information:

```
Type error: layer.canvas is undefined
layer.canvas.setSize(this.attrs.width, this.attrs.height);      kinetic.js (Zeile 3167)
```

As I already figured out the error rise when the code "displayManger.stage.add(cacheGrid) will be executed (displayManager is the outside-class where this code snipped reside).
Can anyone see where I made the mistake? When I directly add the layer grid anything works fine...

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruns8234/gw4JR/4/)

In fiddle you can run both versions by changing one parameter. Hope this helps....

Thanks for help.

Best regards
  Thorsten

Comment: jsfiddle are so much easier to work with, can you make one?

Comment: @nycynik: I've just created my first jsfiddle - and it works (not)

Comment: did you already fix it, i see the red grid in the fiddle.

Comment: @nycynik: No, the jsfiddle has both versions (with and without image caching) included, actual the non-cache version is active (change by parameter useCaching: true/false). If you change parameter the grid will disapear. But answer is already given by Eric below - I missed the correct hierarchy of KineticJS objects - Image couldn't be inserted into stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the problem is simpler than you might think - after caching the layer into an image, you're trying to add an image object directly to the stage (you can't do that).

To fix the problem, you need to create a new layer, say cahcedLayer, add the image to cachedLayer, and then add cachedLayer to the stage.

Check out the KineticJS info page to learn more about Node nesting:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki

Comment: Oh me! I was struck with blindness all the time! You are right! Now it hit's me like a hammer. How could I have missed such an error for more than 5 days!

Answer (score 1):

http://rvillani.com/testes/layer-to-image/
I've made this test and it worked. First, I draw 1000 squares to a layer, add this layer to a hidden stage then make an image from this stage using stage.toDataURL(). When the callback returns, I just create an Image from the data and a Kinetic.Image from the Image. Then I add it to a layer on my main (visible) stage.
Code (be sure to have a div called 'invisible'):

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        width: 520,
        height: 480,
        container: 'container'
    });

    var outerStage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        width: stage.getWidth(),
        height: stage.getHeight(),
        container: 'invisible'
    });

    var layerToCache = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var group = new Kinetic.Group({offset: [stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight()]});

    var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame){
        group.rotate(0.02);
    }, layer);

    var fills = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple', 'cyan',
        'black', 'brown', 'forestgreen', 'gray', 'pink'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        (function ()
         {
            var size = Math.random() * 60 + 20;
            var square = new Kinetic.Rect({
                width: size,
                height: size,
                fill: fills[i % fills.length],
                x: Math.random() * stage.getWidth() - 20,
                y: Math.random() * stage.getHeight() - 20
            });
            layerToCache.add(square);
         })();
    }

    var squaresImg = new Kinetic.Image();
    outerStage.add(layerToCache);
    outerStage.toDataURL({
        callback: function (dataURL){
            outerStage.clear();

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = dataURL;
            img.onload = function () {
                squaresImg.setImage(img);
                squaresImg.setX(squaresImg.getWidth() >> 1);
                squaresImg.setY(squaresImg.getHeight() >> 1);
                group.setX(stage.getWidth() >> 1);
                group.setY(stage.getHeight() >> 1);

                group.add(squaresImg);
                layer.add(group);
                layer.draw();
                anim.start();
            }
        }
    });

    var div = document.getElementById('invisible');
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

    stage.add(layer);
}
```